# How to make a scrollbar with a transparent background

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

How I can hide the scrollbar track, so have the scrollbar thumb with a transparent background?

This is my CSS now:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  display: none; /*I get a white background*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Simply match the background color of the whole scrollbar or the scrollbar track to the background of your scrollable content.

Comment: But can I hide the body's scrollbar and re-implement a new one?

Comment: You can restyle it, and make its background match your body's background.

Comment: I can't because I have an image as background.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this is not possible.